# Как нарисовать полупрозрачный прямоугольник с помощью libgdx?

Tags: java, libgdx

Есть координаты 2-х точек х1, х2, у1, у2. Как нарисовать полупрозрачный прямоугольник на экране по этим 2-м углам с помощью libgdx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого можно использовать `ShapeRenderer`:

```
//Создавать лучше отдельно, а не в методе, чтобы garbage collector не тормозил игру.
ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();

// Если смешивание цветов не включено, включаем так.
Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_BLEND);
Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
// Не забудьте задать матрицу проекции таким образом
shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(myCamera.combined);
shapeRenderer.setColor(red, green, blue, 0.5f);
shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled); 
shapeRenderer.rect(x, y, width, height); 
shapeRenderer.end();
Gdx.gl.glDisable(GL20.GL_BLEND);
```

Тут нужно указывать левый нижний угол и ширину с высотой, но если у вас только две точки противоположных углов, а ширины с высотой нету, то ширину и высоту можно посчитать так:

```
float width = Math.abs(x1 - x2);
float height = Math.abs(y1 - y2);
```

Также, насколько я помню, у `ShapeRenderer` свой `Batch`, поэтому вы должны будете либо останавливать свой `Batch`:

```
myBatch.end();
//рисуем с ShapeRenderer();
myBatch.begin();
//продолжаем рисовать свои спрайты
```

Либо рисовать после того, как нарисуете всё, что нужно и вызовите `end()` своего `Batch`.

Comment: Прямоугольник рисуется, но не полупрозрачный. Будто alpha = 0. Что не так? Код как в примере

Comment: @ИльяКасперский хм, а под "рисуется" вы понимаете то, что код выполняется? просто с alpha 0 ничего не должно рисоваться. По поводу моего кода, проверю сегодня у себя и подумаю еще, чем помочь могу.

Comment: @ИльяКасперский да, нашел проблему, сейчас обновлю ответ

Comment: Спасибо. Одна лишь пометка: надо убрать строку
```java shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(myCamera.combined);```
С ней прямоугольник вообще не рисуется, а без неё норм